# Reactjs on page refresh use current location instead of default page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"` for my current app development. I need a solution to keep my user on current page on page refresh instead going back to the default route (`"/"`).

For example, my user in the `https://example.com/services/plumbing`, while they refresh the page, I want to keep them in the same location instead of default route like `https://example.com/` so the default home page will load. How to do this using `react-router`?

At present, whenever there is a refresh happening, my route update to default, and going back to default location. How to fix this? I do not have any data dependency here.

This is my route:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
        <Route path="/home">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about-us">
          <Aboutus show={-1} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/what-we-do">
          <WhatWeDo />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/projects">
          <Projects />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/contact-us">
          <ContactUs />
        </Route>
      </Suspense>
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
</Router>
```

This is my current `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where should I do the change? What is the change I need do?

Comment: I have always wanted something like this. Your questions is descriptive so hopefully answers will come. I suppose you could save the URL and on refresh, navigate the user to the saved URL? But since the App function is called on refresh, I think it will be very difficult.

Comment: What is the context where the issue is occuring? Your app should not be rerouting to `/` on a local machine, and you should not need an `.htaccess` file  - that's for configuring an apache server. If this is a local dev issue then a [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io) demonstrating it would be useful, otherwise we'll need more info about how your `.htaccess` file is being used in the server directory.

Comment: In local it works fine. no issues. after hosting in to server I face this issue. I provided my .htaccess content for preview. it is placed under apache server. if need more details let me know

Comment: Have you tried looking at this? [Serving Apps with Client-Side Routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)